# In emacs org-agenda clock report, the headline display as ... if it is a long hyperlinks?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In org-agenda, we can use clock report (org-agenda-clockreport-mode) for time spent. Now I encounter such issue:

1) A task header line with long hyperlink format, for example:
* TODO [[outlook:00000000D94CA2AC786588429B27FF9F5ADE02C207003CACBF968BF6D844ACDE08872A34BAA7000000236CFA0000641BF72F869D49499551670BAC68BD2600001BC8C6620000][Just a test email from outlook]]

2) Set the parameter-plist as this, note that I need the ':link t' parameter.
(setq org-agenda-clockreport-parameter-plist
      (quote (:link t :maxlevel 5 :fileskip0 t :compact t :narrow 80)))

3) Generate the clock report in org-agenda (day/weekly), but the Headline only display '...' because it is too long.

How can it remove the [outlook:....] part in the org-agenda-clock-report mode?

Comment: Just curious, do you find that hyperlinks otherwise work in headlines?

Comment: it works by org-outlook.

Comment: I am still facing this problem with clock report in Agenda. Agenda without clock-report just works fine. Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to change your capture template or method of adding tasks to avoid links in headlines.  Links in headlines can cause odd behaviour in the Agenda as well as in exports potentially.

If you change the example to:

```
* TODO Just a test email from Outlook
  [[outlook:00000000D94CA2AC786588429B27FF9F5ADE02C207003CACBF968BF6D844ACDE08872A34BAA7000000236CFA0000641BF72F869D49499551670BAC68BD2600001BC8C6620000][Just a test email from outlook]]
```